Error in pdf-to-printer package in some system
I am using pdf-to-printer package in nodejs for printing directly to selected printer. It's working in most of the systems but in some systems it is showing following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
at forEach (webpack://pdf-to-printer/./src/utils/windows-printer-valid.ts:24:15)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at isValidPrinter (webpack://pdf-to-printer/./src/utils/windows-printer-valid.ts:20:26)
at forEach (webpack://pdf-to-printer/./src/get-printers/get-printers.ts:15:42)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at stdoutHandler (webpack://pdf-to-printer/./src/get-printers/get-printers.ts:14:8)
at i (webpack://pdf-to-printer/./src/get-printers/get-printers.ts:31:12)
at i.next (<anonymous>)
at a (C:\Program Files\Common Files\FOODQUE\kitchenmate-backend\node_modules\pdf-to-printer\dist\bundle.js:1:3525)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Actually printers are working fine in those systems.
Tried all possible printer options in windows. Checked in cmd with wmic printer get name it is showing all printers successfully.
I am not able to check the package file, because I don't have idea about it also it's minified javascript files.
